# Slick Carousel Not Centering Image

Tags: javascript, html, css, slick.js

I've got slick carousel on my page and working. I'm trying to make the images center though I'm not having much luck. I've looked at other questions and tried their solutions but still no luck.

Class for carousel

```
<div class="your-class">
        <div class="ad1img">
            <img src="images/ad1.jpg" /></div>
        <div class="ad2img">
            <img src="images/ad2.jpg" /></div>
        <div class="ad3img">
            <img src="images/ad3.jpg" /></div>
</div>
```

Javascript code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.your-class').slick({
                arrows: false,
                dots: true,
                autoplay: true,
                swipe: false
            });
        });
    </script>
```

CSS

```
.ad1img {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.ad2img {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.ad3img {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

[Carousel Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQfrw.png)

Comment: Use css. I made one example from your code. If it is the solution, try to accept the answer. If it is not the solution, try to be more specific in what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to set an outer div width and then can center the inner contents:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.your-class').slick({
    arrows: false,
    dots: true,
    autoplay: true,
    swipe: false
  });
});
```

```css
.your-class {
  width: 800px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.img-div {
  width: 100%;
}

.img-div img {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/slick/slick.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/slick/slick-theme.css"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/slick/slick.js"></script>

<div class="your-class">
  <div class="img-div" id="ad1img">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x150" />
  </div>

  <div class="img-div" id="ad2img">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x150" />
  </div>

  <div class="img-div" id="ad3img">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x150" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to center you image> See code below
HTML

```html
<div class="your-class">
  <div class="adimg ad1img">
    <img src="" />
  </div>
  
  <div class="adimg ad2img">
    <img src="" />
  </div>
  
  <div class="adimg ad3img">
    <img src="" />
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```css
.adimg img{
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.your-class').slick({
    arrows: false,
    dots: true,
    autoplay: true,
    swipe: false
  });
});
```

```css
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.6.0/slick.css"/><!-- Add the slick-theme.css if you want default styling --><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.6.0/slick-theme.css"/>.your-class {
  width: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.ad1img {
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
}

.ad2img {
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
}

.ad3img {
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/slick/slick.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/slick/slick-theme.css"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/slick/slick.js"></script>

<div class="your-class">
  <div class="img-div" id="ad1img">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x150" />
  </div>

  <div class="img-div" id="ad2img">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x150" />
  </div>

  <div class="img-div" id="ad3img">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x150" />
  </div>
</div>
```